# node.js get all mac contacts

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to get an array list of all my mac contacts in the contacts app without using the node package "osa-contacts" because it does not work like I want it to and it is not that fast. Is there a way to do that? Currently I am using OSX El Capitan 10.11.4.

It is an electron.atom.io app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like [`nodobjc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodobjc), which provides a bridge between Node and the Objective-C runtime (although you probably should already have some Objective-C/Cocoa experience if you want to use it extensively).

Here's an example that prints out the list of contacts by first/last name:

```
var $ = require('nodobjc');

// Load the AddressBook framework.
$.framework('AddressBook');

// Get an instance of the address book for the current user.
var addressBook = $.ABAddressBook('addressBook');

// Retrieve all contacts.
var people = addressBook('people');

// Run through the list of contacts and print their first/last name.
var count = people('count');
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var person    = people('objectAtIndex', i);
  var firstName = person('valueForProperty', $.kABFirstNameProperty);
  var lastName  = person('valueForProperty', $.kABLastNameProperty);
  console.log(i, firstName, lastName);
}
```

I have no idea how much faster (or slower) this is compared to `osa-contacts`, or if it works like you want it. The `AddressBook` framework, which it uses, is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/AddressBook.html).